# JavaFX simpleFloatProperty addition doesnt work

Tags: javafx

I have following method:

```
public void addTransaction(Float value){
    balance.add(value);
}
```

on a class with a property:

```
private SimpleFloatProperty balance;
```

By calling:

```
Obj.addTransaction(Float.parseFloat("-150"));
```

The method is executed, but the balance is not stored. Do you have any ideas why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The add method on `SimpleFloatProperty` does not change the value of the property, it returns creates a new NumberBinding with the summed up value.
Check out the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpressionBase.html#add-javafx.beans.value.ObservableNumberValue-) on NumberExpressionBase.

One way to work around this is to set the added value on the property instead of adding it:

```
public void addTransaction(Float value){
    balance.setValue(value + balance.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are using the methods correctly.  Add returns a NumberBinding - so it's not storing an updated value.

[JavaDoc:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleFloatProperty.html)

Add is inherited from NumberExpressionBase

> public NumberBinding add(ObservableNumberValue other)
>
> Description copied from interface: NumberExpression Creates a new NumberBinding that calculates the sum of this NumberExpression and another ObservableNumberValue.
>
> Specified by:add in interface
>
> NumberExpressionParameters:other - the second
> ObservableNumberValue
>
> Returns:the new NumberBinding

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `SimpleFloatProperty.setValue` instead?

> public void setValue(Number v)
>
> Set the wrapped value

You would have to retrieve the balance's previous value, and add the additional value from your method's input.  Then `setValue` on the sum.